# Dreamweaver cannot open any files

Tags: dreamweaver, osx-mavericks

I am using Dreamweaver CS5.5 on Mac OSX 10.9 it has now stopped opening any files (php, html, css) it displays this error message "filename is a locked file and can be view but not changed" if i click view the file is blank.

I can open all the files in textedit and TextWrangler with full read/write access.

I have tried updating dreamweaver, reinstalling and deleting the file cache

Comment: I have had the same problem on and off. I have yet to find a reason as to why this is working, or how to fix it. Usually if I restart it works, which is not an answer, but that's the only thing that I can do to get it to start working again.